# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable: JSON file

Tags: python, json, binance

I am very unexperienced with Python but I managed to build a full code for what I need.
However, what I believe to be my now last step is to solve this issue i am having with the following message:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
the issue here is I am having a key on the JSON file which ceases to have the particular data I am looking for in the other coins. How can i solve this? or drop the corresponding array?

Can you give me any suggestion? :(

```
def sell_coins():
 
  last_price = get_price()
  for coin in coins_bought:
    if coins_bought[coin]["status"]=="FILLED":
 
      TP = float(coins_bought[coin]["bought_at"]) + (float(coins_bought[coin]["bought_at"]) * TAKE_PROFIT) / 100
      SL = float(coins_bought[coin]["bought_at"]) - (float(coins_bought[coin]["bought_at"]) * STOP_LOSS) / 100

      if float(last_price[coin]["lastPrice"]) > TP or float(last_price[coin]["lastPrice"]) < SL:
        print("TP or SL reached selling", {coins_bought[coin]["volume"]}, {coin})
        sell_limit = client.futures_create_order(
        symbol=coin,
        side="SELL",
        type="MARKET",
        quantity=coins_bought[coin]["volume"])

      else: 
        coins_bought[coin] = None
        with open(coins_bought_file_path, "w") as file:
          json.dump(coins_bought, file, indent=4)
        print("No additional coin to buy or to sell")
```

JSON File: (This is the problem is I am setting this to null/none
{
"SFPUSDT": null
}

Comment: What is `thershold’’’`? It looks like the end of a documentation comment, where's the beginning?

Comment: You have two definitions of the same function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum. Try to ask your question in clear, complete, distinct English sentences, and avoid conversational language.

Comment: you are setting `coins_bought[coin] = None` in some places, however you're also iterating over `coins_bought` and accessing `coins_bought[coin]["status"]` for example - therein lies the issue I suppose.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: @Barmar I think those are just errors in pasting the code into the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the `None` entries from the dictionary before saving to the JSON file.

Comment: i guess adding something like `if coins_bought[coin] is None: continue` at the top of both for loops would be a quick fix for now

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the error because you're trying to access a key in `coins_bought` while the key is `None`. You can reproduce the error by running the code like

```
coins_bought = {}
coins_bought["SFPUSDT"] = None
if coins_bought[coin]["status"]=="FILLED":
    print("FILLED")
```

I think one way to workaround this is to add a check if the key is `None` before checking the condition `coins_bought[coin]["status"]=="FILLED"`

```
if (coins_bought[coin] is not None) and (coins_bought[coin]["status"]=="FILLED"):
    ....
```